# How to load gif using wxWidgets c++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need your help! Im currently really new to wxWidgets as a uni student. I am trying to load a .gif file using wxWidgets. I tried using the code below... but it only loads 1 frame, it doesn't move/ change to the other frames, it's basically a still picture. The file is .gif extension, and it has 3 frames or so. The location of the image is already correct. Help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

```
#include "ImageWindow.h"
#include <wx/stdpaths.h>
#include <wx/filename.h>
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ImageWindow, wxWindow)
EVT_PAINT(ImageWindow::OnPaint)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
ImageWindow::ImageWindow(wxFrame *parent)
    : wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(*wxWHITE));
    wxImageHandler *gifLoader = new wxGIFHandler();
    wxImage::AddHandler(gifLoader);
    this->LoadPotatoBitmap();
}
ImageWindow::~ImageWindow()
{
    delete potatoBitmap;
}
void ImageWindow::LoadPotatoBitmap()
{
    wxStandardPaths &stdPaths = wxStandardPaths::Get();
    wxString fileLocation = stdPaths.GetExecutablePath();
    wxImage image(wxT("A:\\Projects\\TestGif\\Assets\\Kuning.gif"),
        wxBITMAP_TYPE_GIF);
    potatoBitmap = new wxBitmap(image);
}
void ImageWindow::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent &event)
{
    wxPaintDC pdc(this);
    if (potatoBitmap != nullptr)
    {
        pdc.DrawBitmap(*potatoBitmap, wxPoint(150, 100), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `static int  GetImageCount (const wxString &filename, wxBitmapType type=wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY)` then you have to manually draw each frame (image).

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the index of the image in the constructor and that's why you see the default one as you can see in [the wxWdigets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_image.html):

```
wxImage::wxImage    (   const wxString &    name,
    wxBitmapType    type = wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY,
    int     index = -1 
)
```

> **index**  Index of the image to load in the case that the image file contains multiple images. This is only used by GIF, ICO and TIFF handlers. The default value (-1) means "choose the default image" and is interpreted as the first image (index=0) by the GIF and TIFF handler and as the largest and most colourful one by the ICO handler.

But, you should also consider wxAnimationCtrl (see [this sample](https://github.com/LuaDist/wxwidgets/blob/master/samples/animate/anitest.cpp))

Comment: I added -1, but it still results the same. :/

Comment: Default is -1, and means what the quote says it means. If you omit putting anything, you are using the default. Please check 0,1,2, etc. to obtain something less boring.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wxAnimationCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_animation_ctrl.html) for playing gif animations
or

Use extract each frame from the gif image and draw one by one using wxTimer.